# How to price touch options using quantlib?

Tags: option-pricing, programming, quantlib

I am new to [`quantlib`](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml) and I want use it to to price a touch option (single/double).

I searched on google for example code but I could not find anything. Hence, I am not sure if `quantlib` supports touch option.

Could you please give me some pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Touch option is simply a barrier option in QuantLib. You could create one like a down-in barrier type. You can also set the payoff to a binary payoff. The payoff is represented by the StrikePayOff class. A comprehensible example is available on github [here](https://github.com/lballabio/quantlib/blob/master/QuantLib/test-suite/barrieroption.cpp).